# How to check the prerequisites and then start the application using DI?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

My application sould check its settings at startup and only then start.
I'm trying to figure out how to deal with it using DI container. On one hand I don't want to put this self-check into composition root. On the other hand if this check fails then we don't need to register all types with DI container and may simply exit.

So I think of some 2-phase DI. At the first stage only types required during self-check are registered and at the second stage the whole set of types is registered and application object resolved and started. But I don't see how it can be done.

How would you deal with such a situation? I'm using Autofac.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a two phase approach, you could initially build the container with the core application components.  You would then resolve these and run your checks.  If the checks pass, you could then update the container with the reflected plugins by using the [`Update`](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/NewInV2#Adding_to_an_Existing_Container) container method.

However, do you need DI for your settings validation types?  Why not just use them directly before you build the container?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try using Update().

Some validation is performed by the components themselves so using container here seems convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you well.

Why would you bother to do that ?

When your application check fails, you simply exit the application and the container is disposed and all instances released. The fact of registering even houndred of components in your DI container doesn't hurt your performance that much.

Comment: I use pluggable modules in application. When configuring the container I load them via reflection and register types from them. It can take time.

Comment: And e.g. connection strings are injected into data access components and the existence of connection strings in configuration files is part of self-check.

Comment: For registration purposes I don't think there is an easy solution for that. Maybe MEF would be better for that as it offers other options for plugin based applications.